# ADF Master Detail update

Tags: oracle-adf, master-detail

I have master detail page.
Master table has the primary with the combinations of 3 fields (country code, field name and effective date). 
From the above, effective date can be modified.
So whenever we change the effective date, I need to udpate the corresponding childs records also. the table structure below.

```
MASTER
COUNTRY_CODE - PK
FIELD_NAME - PK
EFFECTIVE_DATE - PK

CHILD 
COUNTRY_CODE FK
FIELD_NAME - FK
EFFECTIVE_DT - FK
SOME_FIELD
SOME_FIELDVALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You better not have a PK based on editable table columns, af:table doesn't support it. Instead, you would need a PK based on an immutable attribute (column)